# How can I get rid of the white space on the right side of page?

Tags: html, css

I just finished the landing page for a nonprofit's holiday campaign. I am having a little trouble with some little finishing touches.

Currently, there is extra white space on the right side of the page triggering the horizontal scroll bar in browsers. I am not sure why, I'd like for the page width to adjust to screen size along with the elements.

Also, I am having trouble with the styling of the four images of the people being featured. I'd like the images to display on the same row with no spacing in between when screen is minimum 1200 pixels, each image is 300 x 300 pixels. Otherwise, I'd like them stacked one on top of each other centered on the screen (for mobile). They are stacking, but are displayed to the left.

I am not the savviest of programmers as I am NOT a web developer. I am actually a the Social Media Specialist for the nonprofit. I appreciate your help.

Page can be accessed here:

https://secure3.convio.net/little/site/SPageNavigator/Holiday%20Page%20Wrapper/HolidayCampaign2015.html

Comment: Why do you have `p` tags inside of `style` tags?

Comment: I noticed that too and thought it was weird. I didn't code that portion of the style sheet. It was done by Blackbaud when they initially created our page wrappers for donation forms and all that stuff. I actually went through and removed a few but was hesitant to remove the rest for fear of breaking something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing you can do is wrap everything inside  tag to a new div & set overflow:hidden;

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

    Every other HTML will go here...

  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

ALSO: It is not best practice to call scripts/css inside body tag. Those should be called inside   tags

Comment: Wait, actually adding that tag cut off the top of my header. :(

Comment: I tweaked and set `overflow-x: hidden;` and it worked perfectly, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try placing everything in a **Wrapper** div with the folowing css:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You could also try playing around with:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the whitespace (and scrollbar being displayed), add CSS for `.row { margin: 0 !important; }`. You currently have `-10px +10px`... I never understood why that was the bootstrap standard.

For centering the images, you want to add `margin: 0 auto;` to the parent `div.box` of the image.

Comment: I agree that the negative margin on the `.row` seems useless, but simply adding the `margin: 0 !important;` wouldn't be the best solution in this case, as it breaks the current design on the page (header and the images of people will have gaps). Additional fixes would be needed.

Comment: Thanks, the margin:0 auto; for the div.box did the trick. I didn't try the .row suggestion just because of what shirfy said.

Comment: Any ideas on how to remove the spacing between the images and how to prevent bootstrap from cropping images when screen size is smaller?

Answer (score 0):

Apply this to your CSS maybe styles.css it looks to be the stylesheet with the highest priority.

```
html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}


*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* place this div right aftter thr <body> and before the </body> */

#jar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I forgot to post a solution for your images. This code applies to an element wrapped around the images. Most people use a <`div>`, but I'm using a `<figure>` since it's semantically proper.

Using [`max-content`](http://thenewcode.com/894/Shrink-Wrap-HTML-containers-with-max-content) on a container like `.frame` makes it act like shrink wrap. You need to use the vendor prefixes which is a pain as you can see you have to write out height and width 3 times each.

You might have to use negative margins and reset padding and borders to 0 in order to get rid of the space in between the images.

```css
.frame {
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: max-content;
  height: -moz-max-content;
  height: -webkit-max-content;
  height: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
}
.frame img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: -2px;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<figure class="frame">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x85/000/Fff.png&text=FIRST" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x85/048/Fee.png&text=SECOND" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x85/fa8/375.png&text=THIRD" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x85/9a7/a10.png&text=FOURTH" />
</figure>
```

Comment: This cuts off the page after the 4 images of the features people. :(

Comment: Up and down , like vertically?  Add this property to the `#jar`    `overflow-y: auto;` I'll update to the post as well.

Comment: Yeah, the elements after those images weren't showing.

Comment: What element are you referencing as #jar (it's just a name picked arbitrarily)? Where are you placing the CSS in an external CSS file? Or at the bottom of the `</head>`?

Comment: I placed it in the head. I didn't try it using the `overflow-y: auto;` since another solution that was suggested worked perfectly. I'm sure that would solve the problem though. I'll toy around with the margin stuff since I had removed those elements before due to a suggestion below, but didn't make a difference in what they suggested it solved.

Comment: So the other solution fixed your image problem as well I take it? No worries, as long as you found a solution. ;-)

Comment: No, I still can't figure out the image problem. Honestly, I just gave up. It's not that big of a deal. Aside from the space between the images, as the screen gets smaller, the images get squished together cutting them off on the right. I think it has to do with bootstrap. I have no idea how to fix it and I am tired of it. lol

Comment: Ah, Bootstrap is a pisser. Imo your site is fine, good luck to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is all this margin fudging:

```
@media (min-width: 480px)
.row {
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.row, #content-wrapper .fc-section__inner, .fc-section-outer .fc-section-row, #testimonial .fc-section__inner, footer .fc-section__inner {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}

.row, #content .fc-section__inner, #testimonial .fc-section__inner, footer .fc-section__inner {
   margin-left: -15px;
   margin-right: -15px;
}
```

After I turned all that off, things seemed to line up correctly.

Comment: I took all this out and it still didn't fix the problem. Thanks for the suggestion though.